# how to get array value by using index value of another value?

Tags: arrays, swift

```
let nameArray = ["ramesh","suresh","rajesh"]

let idArray = ["100","101","102"]
```

Now i want value of "idArray" by using index value of "nameArray".

if nameArray index is 0. Output is 100

Comment: And how do you get the index from the first table? U

Comment: Consider to use a custom struct rather than two arrays

Comment: Actually I am passing nameArray to one dropdown by selecting i am getting index value. @JoakimDanielson

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Object Oriented Programming, objects should own their properties. So instead of having two data structures describe the same object, either use structs like **Mr. Vadian** has suggested, or have one array store all the properties of the objects:

```
let zippedArray = Array(zip(nameArray, idArray))
```

And now to get the object in a given index, you can use the following:

```
let index = 0
let element = zippedArray[0]
print(element.0)              //ramesh
print(element.1)              //100
```